# UTP Stereotype <<TestLog>> in Rhapsody

Tags: testing, uml, rhapsody

I am creating a model in Rhapsody in which I am using TestingPtofile. I want to use **TestLog** stereotype which is defined in OMG UTP documentation as following:

[image]

I need all the attributes i.e. tester, executedAt, duration, verdict and verdictReason available in TestLog Stereotype. I am using Rhapsody designer version 8.1.4, but I am unable to find TestLog Stereotype in Rhapsody TestingProfile. I am open to using any other stereotype(s) available in Rhapsody profile to set those attributes but I can't find anything appropriate.

Can someone please suggest what is equivalent of UTP TestLog in Rhapsody TestingProfile.

Answer (score 0):

I created an IBM service request to find out if TestLog stereotype is available in Rhapsody or not. They answered that it is not available in Rhapsody and suggested to provide a workaround.